# cout cutting off beginning of string in for loop

Tags: c++

I have a double for loop going through a two-dimensional array of object classes, and there is supposed to be a repeated message every time it loops to give specific information, but the strings that are the same every time keep getting cut off at the front more each time it loops. What is the reason why it keeps doing this? I have never had this problem before while using C++.

```
System systems[29][119];
string ds[29][119];
int sx = 0;
int sy = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++) {
    for (int o = 0; o < 119; o++) {
        int which = rand() % 4 + 1;
        system("cls");
        cout << "X: " + o << endl << "Y: " + i << endl << endl;
        if (which == 1) {
            systems[i][o] = genSystem(o, i);
            cout << "ID: " + systems[i][o].id << endl
                << "Num Planets: " + systems[i][o].numPlanets << endl;
            system("pause >nul");
        }
        else {
            systems[i][o] = genSystem(o, i, false);
            cout << "NO SYSTEM" << endl;
            system("pause >nul");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I would think it's probably a bug in your code.  Do you have access to / know how to use a debugger?  Because people who post on SO are not debuggers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For issues like this please always include the output. Thank you :).

Comment: Use << instead of operator + to prevent this problem.

Answer (score 9):

You’re adding numbers to string literals (which represent arrrays), which ultimately boils down to pointer arithmetic.
It does not "stringify" the numbers and concatenate them as it would in some other languages.

```
"Hello" + 1 —> "ello"
"Hello" + 2 —> "llo"
```

And so on.

Use `<<` instead of `+`.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your numbers in `cout` by `<<` instead of using the arithmetic operator `+` to add an offset.